# Lazarus pascal/Delphi - Child form is not editable

Tags: forms, delphi, parent-child, lazarus

I'm creating a new instance of a form and trying to show it as a child from on a PANEL. But The form doesn't seem to be usable. I mean I cannot edit any textbox. But there are other controls like the tree and button that **seem** clickable.

Here is the code:

```
procedure TForm1.ProcfrmSetupItemCategories;
var
  NewForm: TfrmSetupItemCategories;
begin
  NewForm:=TfrmSetupItemCategories.Create(BodyPanel);

  NewForm.Parent := BodyPanel;
  NewForm.Top:=5;
  NewForm.Left:=5;
  NewForm.Show;
end;
```

But if I remove the line `NewForm.Parent := BodyPanel;` the form is editable but it goes out of the parent form/Panel.

Also when the parent is set, the child form is not active (looking at the title bar)

Am I missing something? Please advice.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you add some more detail on why do you need to use a Form and stick it onto a panel, what do you want to achieve. Maybe better solution would be to use `TFrame`.

Comment: Is `BodyPanel.Enabled = True` ?

Comment: @TomHagen BodyPanel is Enabled. In fact it is done at design time so nothing to change there.

Comment: @KromStern Since we don't have MDI forms I've create two panels. The left panel contains buttons for menus (like an accordion). The right panel is the body panel. I'm making the other forms use the Panel as parent so that if the main form moves the others move with it. Also the other forms (child forms) would not go out of the panel area.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Lazarus; I've got to live without MDIs since I'm trying to make this work on Linux as well

Answer (score 0):

A Form needs to be a child of other forms or TApplication. The TPanel does not know how to manage forms so your form will not get activated and its components will not receive focus.

Instead you could use normal forms and write a procedure to align your forms. Now add a timer to your main form and call the alignment procedure from the ontimer event.  As the user moves or resizes the main form, the other forms re-align.

Dave Peters
DP Software

Comment: Coming from a VB environment, I don't see any sense in using a timer. what actually is the reason for a time here?

Comment: You need to check if the user moves the main form so you can adjust the position of your other forms to suit.  You will not know when the form is moved so set up a timer that expires every few hundred ms and then in the ontimer event you can check if the forms need moving.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not very sure if this is an elegant or efficient way of moving the child form. It seems workable but I think this is not a good idea particularly for a powerful OOP language like feepascal. Wouldn't it be better to create a new class that contains the child form and have a constructor that puts the initial position, and then use a method that resets the position on moving the parent form?

Comment: How do you know when to call your method ? - As fas as I know, there is no onmove event for a form.

Comment: I ain't chalenging anyone. I'm just thinking from a technical point of view and as a person having done this in VB, I don't see it as efficient. Perhaps I've got to dig in further. And if I cannot find a solution, I think your method would be *the only option* ;)

Comment: I never learn't VB but I do use the timer method in my MAC software under development using Delphi XE3 so if you do find a better solution please let me know. You are right its not a great solution but so far the only one I can find. If you can get away without using forms but instead use panels then you can use the parent panel to do the organising. For pure delphi VCL there are already dockable panel solutions available - not sure about Lazarus.

Comment: Panel's can be parents of forms. And TApplication cannot be a form's parent. Timers are absolutely not the solution here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan +1 for your input. It confirmed that there was a better way ;)